# Rails route - undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, routes, undefined

Just getting started with Rails and I am having a problem defining a route.  None of the documentation I can seems to resolve the issue and I am getting an undefined local variable or method error.

I need to click on a link and take a specific action, sortit.  sortit does not have a view because it sorts mystuff objects and then redirects to the index page.  When I use one of the predefined actions then in fact everything works.  Of course none of the predefined actions are what I want to do.

my /config/routes.rb file:

```
match "/mystuff/sortit'", :controller => "mystuff", :action => "sortit"

resources :mystuff
```

my /app/controllers/mystuff_controller.rb file

```
class MystuffController < ApplicationController
....
  def sortit
     @mystuff.sort
     redirect_to_mystuff_path
  end
....
end
```

my /app/views/mystuff/index.html.haml file:

```
-#  This file is app/views/mystuff/index.html.haml
%h1 All My Stuff

%table#mystuff
  %thead
    %tr
      %th= link_to raw("Type"), sortit
 ....
```

As I said, when I replace sortit with a predefined action, then that action is executed.  However sortit fails with this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `sortit' for #<#<Class:0x9997a10>:0x997c0f8>
app/views/mystuff/index.html.haml:7:in `_app_views_mystuff_index_html_haml__61272557_87671610'
```

So what have I missed and how do I get sortit to execute when clicking on the generated link for Type?

Thanks!

PS: My rake routes output:

mystuff GET  /mystuff (.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"mystuff"}

....

mystuff_sortit  /mystuff/sortit (.:format)  {:controller=>"mystuff", :action=>"sortit"}

....

So rake routes shows my route with the name mystuff_sorit - but aren't actions prepended to the object name?  Shouldn't it be sortit_mystuff instead?

Comment: Of course mystuff above is actually mystuffs ....

Comment: I think you want to add a key to the route match line for :as => 'sortit', then call sortit_path or sortit_url instead of just sortit.

Comment: @Thanatos - thanks - that didn't generate an error just when the index.html page is displayed although when I clicked on the sortit link it still fails. In routes.rb I added the :as
in the routes - and sortit_url in index.html.haml.  However where is this documented?  :action=>"sortit" is specified.  Why is :as needed at all?  Also where is the _url "suffix" documented?
<p>routes.rb:</p>
<p>match "/mystuff/sortit'", :controller => "mystuff", :action => "sortit", :as=>"sortit"
</p>
<p> %th= link_to raw("Type"), sortit_url</p>

Comment: @Thantos - that change resulted in this change in the rake routes output: sortit /mystuff/sortit (.:format) {:controller=>"mystuff", :action=>"sortit"}  - so where is the code generating actually documented in detail?

Comment: This does result in a url being generated for Type: <a href="/mystuff/sortit">Type</a> - but now an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error is being thrown and a show action is apparently being tried to execute:ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MystuffController#show Couldn't find Mystuff with id=sortit app/controllers/mystuff_controller.rb:5:in `show'

Answer (score 0):

Your action is `sortit` but your view is `index`

Change your action to `index`

`redirect_to` needs a space also, so use `redirect_to mystuff_path`...
which will actually be `my_stuffs_path` (plural) which you can see from `rake routes` (at the command line, most useful) which you get from defining it as a resource in routes.

Comment: sortit is a real action.  It has to be implemented.  It doesn't have a view because it sorts a list of mystuff and then the index page is redisplayed.  I edited the original post with the first two lines of the rakes routes output

Comment: index is also an action that's implemented.  it's a good idea to add the sorting to it (as an option).